# Retrieve the first OU in search of distinguishedName attribute

Tags: java

I am using Spring Security 3.1 Active Directory.

I have a AD structure, where I need to get an OU value out of the AD structural distinguishedName attribute.

The OU that I want, will always be the first OU after the last DC.

below is my code example - **I need to get the myCompany OU value**, there must be a better way to do this:

public class Test {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String s = "cn=harry,cn=group,ou=myCompany,ou=customers,dc=this,dc=that";

    System.out.println("s: "+s);

    String s1 = s.substring(s.indexOf("ou=") + 3);

    System.out.println("s1: "+s1);

    String s2 = s1.substring(s1.indexOf(""), s1.indexOf(",ou="));

    System.out.println("s2: "+s2);

}
```

}

This outputs the following:

```
s: cn=harry,ou=myCompany,ou=customers,dc=this,dc=that 
s1: myCompany,ou=customers,dc=this,dc=that 
s2: myCompany
```

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex! Pick your flavor below (first or second):

```
public static void main (String[] args){
     String s = "cn=harry,cn=group,ou=users,ou=myCompany,ou=customers,dc=this,dc=that";

     String first = s.replaceAll(".*?,ou=(.*?),.*", "$1");
     String middle = s.replaceAll(".*?,ou=.*?,ou=(.*?),.*", "$1");
     String third = s.replaceAll(".*,ou=(.*?),.*", "$1");

     System.out.println(first);
     System.out.println(middle);
     System.out.println(third);
}
```

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake. I need this to always be the second OU, not the first?

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate the quick response. as it goes I have investigated that the String is acutally: String s = "cn=harry,ou=users,ou=myCompany,ou=customers,dc=this,dc=that" and I need to be able to be the get the middle ou which is myCompany. Could you help with this please?

Comment: Updated the answer. Don't forget to close the question and vote up if you think it helps. Cheers

Comment: That's great does exactly what I need!

Comment: Try to find the time to learn regular expressions. They are extremely handy